# Can T-43 lens be reused on SLR camera?

Tags: film, slr, contax

I've done half of a stupid thing that is: I've bought a Smena 8M thinking that I will adapt the lens easy. In my rush I've disassembled the T-43 shutter mechanism without knowing that the lens can easily be detached.
When I've tried the lens with my Contax C/Y is working if it is resting on the body mount but this means that the Lens will clash with the mirror.

To resume my question it is possible and useable to mount the T-43 on a teleconverter?

This way the lens will not clash with the mirror.

Comment: I suspect it would not work.  Do you have a teleconverter to test?

Comment: @xiota I don't. Do I have any other alternative?

Comment: Older, basic mirrorless cameras go from about $100 used ... get one if you want to experiment with hackdapted lenses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have access to a T-22 (similar to T-43).  The flange focal distance is very short.  It can be used as a close-up or macro lens on SLRs, but will not be able to focus to infinity.

Teleconverters are designed to work with lenses that have FFD that match your camera.  Since the T-43 has a shorter FFD, it's unlikely to work.  I tried the T-22 with an OM mount 2x teleconverter, and the lens hits the TC optics without being able to focus on anything even just a few feet away.  I don't have a C/Y teleconverter, but would expect similar results.

The best option for adapting lenses is to use mirrorless cameras because the FFD is shorter and there's no mirror in the way.